# ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 5 while creating a table space in linux

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, database-administration, ubuntu-22.04

### The problem

I want to create a table space in the directory between single quotes but it gives me the error

```sql
CREATE TABLESPACE PRUEBA5 DATAFILE '/home/ram/db/prueba5.dbf' 
SIZE 1M 
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 200K MAXSIZE 1400K
DEFAULT STORAGE (INITIAL 16K NEXT 16K MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 3);
```

if i go just putting the name of the file the table space is created in `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs`.
I am using ubuntu.

### The question

how could i create this datafile without avoiding the use of a specific directory?

Comment: What permissions does the user that Oracle runs as have on the directory `/home/ram/db/`?

Comment: how can i see it?

Comment: `ls -l  /home/ram/db/` at the command prompt would probably show most of what you need, although you might also need know what group the Oracle user belongs to.

Comment: Oracle usually runs under a dedicated account (e.g. `oracle`) and group, while your home directory is owned by you and usually isn't accessible to anyone else (for security reasons). You could relax permissions on your directory so that the Oracle user can read and write to it, but that may not be a great idea; it would be better to keep the data file with the others, or at least somewhere outside anyone's home directory. Why do you want it in that specific location?

Comment: it was just a college practice, but all people is using windows, i got lost and no one could help me nevertheless, thank you all for your time!